# arc length of $y = \frac{x^{2}}{8} - \log(x)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am having trouble with the resulting integral for the curve length

The function is

$y = \frac{x^{2}}{8}  - \log(x)$

And the points are

$x_1 = 1, x_2 = e$

$$\int_{1}^{e}\sqrt{1 + (x/4 - 1/x)^2 } dx$$

how it is possible to make a substitution for $\frac x4 - \frac 1 x$?

I'd like to make it $\tan\omega$ to get the obvious $1 + \tan^2$

Comment: Write clearly what your function is...

Comment: It's well known that the arc length of just the parabola is complicated. Throwing in the log would make it really annoying. Good luck.

Comment: The inside of the square root should become a perfect square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the fact that\begin{align}1+\left(\frac x4-\frac1x\right)^2&=1+\frac{x^2}{16}-\frac12+\frac1{x^2}\\&=\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac12+\frac1{x^2}\\&=\left(\frac x4+\frac1x\right)^2.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You will get
$$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{4}-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{(x+4)^2}{x^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what happens
with the indefinite integral.

$\begin{array}\\
\int\sqrt(1 + (x/4 - 1/x)^2 ) dx
&=\int\sqrt(1 +x^2/16-1/2+1/x^2) dx\\
&=\int\sqrt(x^2/16+1/2+1/x^2) dx\\
&=\int\sqrt((x/4+1/x)^2) dx\\
&=\int(x/4+1/x) dx\\
&=\frac18 x^2 +  \log(x)\\
\end{array}
$

Ha!
Not complicated at all!

From 1 to $e$ it's

$\frac{e^2}{8}+1-\frac18
=\frac{e^2}{8}+\frac78
$.

Comment: Then why did you say that the log would make it more complicated?

Comment: My first impression was wrong. The additional term log x was cleverly chosen to make the result come out nicely.